# load always data for only one index range

Tags: react-virtualized

Sorry if the title is somewhat misleading. I'm using an `InfiniteLoader` with a `Table` and the problem is that almost always the total number of data I want to load is huge. And if I were to append the data every time `loadMoreRows` was called, I would end up storing maybe more than 100000 entries in the state, which I think would be bad for performance.

I was wondering if it's possible to not append data everytime. I tried only setting the logs and the status to loaded only from `startIndex` to `stopIndex`, but every time I scroll `loadMoreRows` is called multiple times.

Here is what I have so far, with what I tried as mentioned above

```
'use strict';

import React = require('react');
import _ = require('lodash');
import Immutable = require('immutable');
import moment = require('moment-timezone');
import {AutoSizer, InfiniteLoader, Table, Column} from 'react-virtualized';

interface Props {
    logEntries: Immutable.List<Immutable.Map<string, any>>;
    count: number;
    timezone: string;
    logLimit: number;
    loadedRowsMap: { [index: number]: number; };
    onLoadMoreRows: (param: {startIndex: number, stopIndex: number}) => Promise<any>;
}

class LogLoader extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    render() {
        const {logEntries, count, logLimit} = this.props;
        const headers: {
            name: string;
            dataKey: string;
            width: number;
            cellDataGetter?: (param: {rowData: any}) => any;
        }[] = [
            { name: 'Time', dataKey: 'dtCreated', width: 95, cellDataGetter: this.renderTime.bind(this) },
            { name: 'Level', dataKey: 'levelname', width: 65 },
            { name: 'Message', dataKey: 'message', width: 70, cellDataGetter: this.renderMessage.bind(this) }
        ];

        return (
            <InfiniteLoader isRowLoaded={this.isRowLoaded.bind(this)}
                            loadMoreRows={this.props.onLoadMoreRows}
                            minimumBatchSize={logLimit}
                            rowCount={count} >
                {
                    ({onRowsRendered, registerChild}) => (
                        <AutoSizer disableHeight>
                            {
                                ({width}) => (
                                    <Table headerHeight={20}
                                           height={400}
                                           onRowsRendered={onRowsRendered}
                                           rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
                                           ref={registerChild}
                                           rowCount={count}
                                           className='log-entries'
                                           gridClassName='grid'
                                           headerClassName='header'
                                           rowClassName={this.getRowClassName.bind(this)}
                                           rowGetter={({index}) => logEntries.get(index)}
                                           rowHeight={this.calculateRowHeight.bind(this)}
                                           width={width} >
                                        {
                                            headers.map(({name, dataKey, cellDataGetter, width}) => 
                                                <Column label={name}
                                                        key={name}
                                                        className={`${name.toLowerCase()} column`}
                                                        dataKey={dataKey}
                                                        cellDataGetter={cellDataGetter || this.renderTableCell.bind(this)}
                                                        width={width} />
                                            )
                                        }
                                    </Table>
                                )
                            }
                        </AutoSizer>
                    )
                }
            </InfiniteLoader>
        );
    }

    private calculateRowHeight({index}) {
        const rowData = this.props.logEntries.get(index);
        if(!rowData) {
            return 0;
        }
        const msg = this.renderMessage({rowData});

        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const span = document.createElement('span');
        span.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';
        span.style.wordBreak = 'break-all';
        span.style.fontSize = '12px';
        span.style.fontFamily = 'monospace';
        span.style.display = 'table-cell';
        span.innerHTML = msg;

        div.appendChild(span);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        const height = div.offsetHeight;
        document.body.removeChild(div);

        return height;
    }

    private rowRenderer(params: any) {
        const {key, className, columns, rowData, style} = params;
        if(!rowData) {
            return (
                <div className={className}
                     key={key}
                     style={style} >
                    Loading...
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div className={className}
                 key={key}
                 style={style} >
                {columns}
            </div>
        );
    }

    private renderTableCell({rowData, dataKey}) {
        if(!rowData) {
            return null;
        }

        return rowData.get(dataKey);
    }

    private renderMessage({rowData}) {
        if(!rowData) {
            return null;
        }

        return rowData.get('message');
    }

    private renderTime({rowData}) {
        if(!rowData) {
            return null;
        }

        return moment(rowData.get('dtCreated'))
            .tz(this.props.timezone)
            .format('HH:mm:ss.SSS');
    }

    private getRowClassName({index}) {
        const {logEntries} = this.props;
        const data = logEntries.get(index);

        if(data) {
            return `log-entry ${data.get('levelname').toLowerCase()}`;
        }

        return '';
    }

    private isRowLoaded({index}) {
        return !!this.props.loadedRowsMap[index];
    }
}

export = LogLoader;
```

and here is `loadMoreRows` passed down from the parent component

```
private loadMoreRows({startIndex, stopIndex}) {
    const {loadedRowsMap, logEntries} = this.state,
          indexRange = _.range(startIndex, stopIndex + 1),
          updatedLoadedRowsMap = {};

    indexRange.forEach(i => { updatedLoadedRowsMap[i] = STATUS_LOADING; });
    this.setState({ loadedRowsMap: updatedLoadedRowsMap, loading: true });

    return Api.scriptLogs(null, { id: this.props.id })
        .then(({body: [count, logs]}) => {
            indexRange.forEach(i => { updatedLoadedRowsMap[i] = STATUS_LOADED; });
            const newLogs = logEntries.splice((stopIndex - startIndex + 1), 0, ...logs).toJS();
            this.setState({
                count,
                logEntries: Immutable.fromJS(newLogs),
                loadedRowsMap: updatedLoadedRowsMap,
                loading: false
            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated answer**

The key to understand what you're seeing involves a few things.

1. First, you are wiping out the `loadedRowsMap` in your example each time you load new rows. (Once you load rows 200-399 you throw away rows 0-199.)
2. You're setting a very large `minimumBatchSize` in your example (200). This tells `InfiniteLoader` that each chunk of rows it loads should- if at all possible- cover a range of at least 200 items.
3. `InfiniteLoader` defines a [`threshold` prop](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/eb50a1569c8a59ec3d296145b636dff4b24ccae8/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js#L48-L53) that controls how far ahead it pre-loads rows. This [defaults to 15](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/eb50a1569c8a59ec3d296145b636dff4b24ccae8/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js#L59), meaning that when you scroll within 15 rows of an unloaded range (eg 185 in your case) it will load a block in advance- with the hope that by the time the user scrolls the rest of the way to that range, it will have been loaded.
4. `InfiniteLoader` [checks both ahead and behind by the `threshold` amount](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/eb50a1569c8a59ec3d296145b636dff4b24ccae8/source/InfiniteLoader/InfiniteLoader.js#L112-L118) since a user could scroll up *or* down and either direction may contain unloaded rows.

This all leads to the following scenario:

1. User scrolls until a new range of rows is loaded.
2. Your demo app throws away the previous range.
3. User scrolls a little further and `InfiniteLoader` checks 15 rows ahead and behind to see if data has been loaded in both directions (as per reason 4 above).
4. Data appears to not have been loaded above/before and so `InfiniteLoader` tries to load at least `minimumBatchSize` records in that direction (eg 0-199)

The solution to this problem could be a few things:

- Don't throw away your previously loaded data. (It probably takes up minimal memory anyway so just keep it around.)
- If you must throw it away- don't throw away all of it. Keep some near the range the user is currently within. (Enough to make sure that a `threshold` check is safe in both directions.)

**Original answer**

Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but this is what the `minimumBatchSize` prop is for. It configures `InfiniteLoader` to load large enough chunks of data that you won't get a lot of repeated load requests as a user is slowly scrolling through the data. If the user scrolls quickly- you might. There's no way around that though.

If that's problematic for you I'd recommend using a debounce and/or throttling approach to prevent firing off too many HTTP requests. Debounce can help you avoid loading rows that a user quickly scrolls past (and wouldn't see anyway) and throttle can help you avoid sending too many HTTP requests in parallel.

At a glance, your `isRowLoaded` function and the mapping done in `loadMoreRows` look right. But you might also want to verify that. `InfiniteLoader` is not stateful- so it will keep asking for the same rows over and over again unless you let it know that they're either loaded already or in the process of being loaded.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Let's see if I can explain it better. Every time `loadMoreRows` is called I just set the data from `startIndex` to `stopIndex`. For example, I store from 0-199 and then from 200-399, so 0-199 is empty. But whenever I scroll somewhere between 200-399, `loadMoreRows` is called for 0-199. I would like it to be called only when I'm about to render the indices before or after my stored data. Is that possible?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. `InfiniteLoader` only scans and requests rows to be loaded that are currently rendered. Have this running anywhere I could see it in action?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I edited my `loadMoreRows` to the version I currently have and the logs I see when `console.log`ging `startIndex` and `stopIndex` are: 200 399, 0 199, 200 399, 0 199, 400 58727(my total count), 133 332. I don't get it honestly

Comment: I created a sample fiddle. Not working there so you have to run it locally if possible. https://jsfiddle.net/XeniaSiskaki/0Ld61rdo/

Comment: This could have been made to work on JSfiddle. It's a lot to ask for someone to setup a local project, install deps, compile TS, etc. to repro a bug. :)

Comment: I'll try to do so. Sorry

Comment: It's okay. I have a working version of it running in Plnkr now @ https://plnkr.co/edit/5AC6jbVng0JgAoWrduki?p=preview

Comment: There is something funky going on but I don't have the time to dig into it now. Day job ;) I'll try to look more this evening.

Comment: I have edited my answer with an explanation of why you are seeing this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136435/discussion-between-xeniasis-and-brianvaughn).